# How do I save a table from big query into colab as a pandas dataframe?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-colaboratory, spring-cloud-gcp-bigquery

I am new to BQ I am trying to save my BQ tables as a pandas dataframe in my colab environment. This is the code I am using but I am getting a "Bad request Error". Any ideas how I can trouble shoot? I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.
**My code is as follows:**

````
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client(project=project_id)

sample_count = 2000
row_count = client.query('''
  SELECT 
    COUNT(*) as total
  FROM `123.cleaned_sales`''').to_dataframe().total[0]

df = client.query('''
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    `123.cleaned_sales`
  WHERE RAND() < %d/%d
''' % (sample_count, row_count)).to_dataframe()

print('Full dataset has %d rows' % row_count)```

Here is my error message 

[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQOox.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image you shared indicates the `projectId` and `datasetId` should not to be empty in this query :

```py
row_count = client.query('''
  SELECT 
    COUNT(*) as total
  FROM `123.cleaned_sales`''').to_dataframe().total[0]
```

You have to set the `projectId` :

```py
row_count = client.query('''
  SELECT 
    COUNT(*) as total
  FROM `your_project_id.123.cleaned_sales`''').to_dataframe().total[0]
```

Do the same with the second query.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but that is not working: 

`project_id = '[sales-forecast-361716]'
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client(project=project_id)

sample_count = 2000
row_count = client.query('''
  SELECT 
    COUNT(*) as total
  FROM `sales-forecast-361716.123.cleaned_sales`''').to_dataframe().total[0]

df = client.query('''
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    `sales-forecast-361716.123.cleaned_sales`
  WHERE RAND() < %d/%d
''' % (sample_count, row_count)).to_dataframe()

print('Full dataset has %d rows' % row_count)`

Comment: do you know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: You put braquets on project ID, can you test without braquets on project ID please ? project_id = 'sales-forecast-361716' I will edit my answer because normally if you set project in the Bigquery client, you not are obliged to passed it in bq queries